# Resolved: How to check multiple email addresses in dynamic fields to check if user already exists or not

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dynamic, colorbox

I am creating a team registration form. and the required condition is that user must be already registered and can choose only registered members in the team.

for checking user existence in database i am using email.
The form contains multiple email fields triggered by a button that adds a field in the form

I need to check for all user's existence when user types in the respective email field using ajax call and display the result in `<span class='form_hint'></span>`

The form is contained in a hidden div and is called by colorbox

but it doesn't seem to work somehow

Here's my html code:

> Update: Now Working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> <head>
<title>Event Description </title>

<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<!--Colorbox-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="colorbox/css/styles.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="colorbox/css/colorbox.css" >

<script src="colorbox/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="colorbox/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".register").colorbox({inline:true,maxHeight:"95%", maxWidth:"90%"} );    
        });
</script>

    <!--Colorbox ends-->

</head>
<body>

<a class="register" href="#register">Event Registeration</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function usercheck(){
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="email"]').keyup(function() {
var name = $(this).val();
if(name=="")
{
$(".form_hint").html("");
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "user_check.php",
data: { email: name } ,
success: function(html){
$(".form_hint").html(html);
}
});
return false;
}
});
});
}
</script>

<div style='display:none'>
  <div id='register' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
    <center>        
    <form class="contact_form" action="../../register/register.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Registration</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" onkeyup="usercheck();" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "mail@example.com"</span>
        </li>
        <span id="dynamicInput"></span>
        <li><input type="button" value="+" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"/></li>
        <li>

         <button class="submit" type="submit">Register</button></h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form></center>
  </div>



</div>





<script type="text/javascript">
function addInput(liName){
    //var counter=1;
    var newfield = document.createElement('li');
    newfield.innerHTML = "<label for='email'>Email:</label><input type='email' name='email[]' onkeyup="usercheck();"  placeholder='mail@example.com' /><span class='form_hint'></span>";
          document.getElementById(liName).appendChild(newfield);


}

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code to check users in Database:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
$name=$_POST['email'];
$query=mysql_query("select * from user_details where email='$name'");
$row=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($row==1)
{
echo "Okay Pal!";
}
else
{
echo "User doesn't exist";
}
}
?>
```

I don't know where the error is as i am implementing it using dynamic fields for very first time

Also i want to know a good method to handle multiple email fields like i am using above.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you have any debug msg from console or log? Put `alert(name);`s everywhere to trace your variables and provide some moar information pls

Comment: @DanFromGermany
I don't know if its sending/receiving the request/response to/from php
is there any way i can check it?

Comment: use Firebug or Chrome's integrated debug tools, it should look like this to see the traffic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ISid.png

Comment: It depends on which browser you're using. But almost all browsers have debug console where you can observe all the requests made to the server and responses. In the Chrome browser `CTRL+SHIFT+J` and go to the Network tab.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think your `IF-Statement` in your PHP-Code is executed.

You're checking for an `email`-parameter, but your ajax-data looks like  `data: "name="+ name`

Try to change it to `data: { email: name }`,

Answer (score 1):

First of all selector `$('#email[]')` is invalid. Try adding some class to the email input or use this selector `$('input[type="email"]')` to add event handler to all email fields.

Next thing is `keyup` handler. Inside handler function you can use `$(this)` instead trying to select field again.

The last one consider using JSON as the data exchange type. On the server return string like: `{registered:true}` and on the client parse it as a JSON in the `jQuery.ajax` function setting `dataType` to JSON.

Comment: I have updated the code above and changed the elements but problem is still there, i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

The Above code is now fully functional.
Earlier only 1st field was calling the function and checking through php. so as to resolve it, I added a

`function usercheck(){}`

to handle the user interactions.

And on every key up on `<input type='email'>` I added `onkeyup()` function that triggers `usercheck()` as:

`<input type='email' name='email[]' onKeyUp='usercheck();'>`

and result of the query is displayed within `<span>` with every `<input type='email'>` field

Thank you everyone for your valuable responses :) You made my day!